# How do I iterate a tuple to perform 2 operations when it is defined within a string?

Tags: python

So I've defined a variable called "position", as a tuple which has two co-ordinates (0,1). I've created a function which has an if condition, that if a string is input by a user, it would increase the position variable by 1.

My question was, how do I get the if function to increase only the 0 co-ordinate of the position variable in the tuple, without changing the 1 co-ordinate? Also, how will it return the input?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question, please try to be as specific as you can about your problem and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code [within your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Tuples are immutable, this is not possible by definition. You need to create a new tuple.

Comment: If you are going to be changing that variable all the time, you should be using a list instead of tuple: `[0, 1]`. As mentioned, tuples are immutable while lists are mutable. And then just change by doing `position[0] = new_val`

Answer (score 1):

You can't *modify* a tuple, only return a modified version

```
def update(my_tuple):
    x, y = my_tuple
    return (x+1, y)
```